# phoenix translate msg without put_locale

Tags: phoenix-framework

I have an array of users, each with its own locale.

I need to get a translation of the message into the language of each user.

```
...
Enum.map(user.tokens, fn(t) -> t.token end)
|> Sender.send(translated_msg(user.locale, msg))
...
  defp translated_msg(locale, msg) do
    message = Gettext.with_locale MyApp.Gettext, locale, fn ->
      MyApp.Gettext.gettext(msg.body, msg.bindings)
    end
    message
  end
```

where

```
msg = %{body: "%{login} added a new operation", bindings: %{login: current_user.login}}
```

But such code is not compiled

```
== Compilation error on file web/helpers/sender_helper.ex ==
** (ArgumentError) *gettext macros expect translation keys (msgid and msgid_plural) and
domains to expand to strings at compile-time, but the given msgid
doesn't.

Dynamic translations should be avoided as they limit gettext's
ability to extract translations from your source code. If you are
sure you need dynamic lookup, you can use the functions in the Gettext
module:

    string = "hello world"
    Gettext.gettext(MyApp.Gettext, string)

    (gettext) lib/gettext/compiler.ex:196: anonymous fn/2 in Gettext.Compiler.expand_to_binary/4
    expanding macro: MyApp.Gettext.dgettext_noop/2
    web/helpers/push_helper.ex:23: MyApp.SenderHelper.translated_msg/2
    expanding macro: MyApp.Gettext.dgettext/3
    web/helpers/push_helper.ex:23: MyApp.SenderHelper.translated_msg/2
    expanding macro: MyApp.Gettext.gettext/1
    web/helpers/push_helper.ex:23: MyApp.SenderHelper.translated_msg/2
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:117: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1
```

How can I manually translate a message into another language?

Comment: Does changing `MyApp.Gettext.gettext(msg.body, msg.bindings)` to `Gettext.gettext(MyApp.Gettext, msg.body, msg.bindings)` work?

Comment: @Dogbert, yes, it works, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like the error message says, if the string to translate is dynamic, you need to use `Gettext.gettext/{2,3}` passing in your app's `Gettext` module as the first argument. Since you're passing bindings as well, you need to use `Gettext.gettext/3`:

```
Gettext.gettext(MyApp.Gettext, msg.body, msg.bindings)
```